# Creating a new column in a data frame whose entries depend on multiple columns in a another data frame

Tags: r

I want to make new column in my data set with the values determined by values in another data set, but it's not as simple as the values in one column being a function of the values in the other. Here's an example:

```
 >df1  
      chromosome position
1              1        1
2              1        2
3              1        4
4              1        5
5              1        7
6              1       12
7              1       13
8              1       15
9              1       21
10             1       23
11             1       24
12             2        1
13             2        5
14             2        7
15             2        8
16             2       12
17             2       15
18             2       18
19             2       21
20             2       22
```

and

```
>df2
  chromosome segment_start segment_end segment.number
1          1             1           5            1.1
2          1             6          20            1.2
3          1            21          25            1.3
4          2             1           7            2.1
5          2             8          16            2.2
6          2            18          22            2.3
```

I want to make a new column in df1 called 'segment', and the value in segment is to be determined by which segment (as determined by 'segment_start', 'segment_end', and 'chromosome' from df2) the value in 'position' belongs to. For example, in df1, row 7, position=13, and chromosome=1. Because 13 is between 6 and 20, the entry in my hypothetical 'segment' column would be 1.2, from row 2 of df2, because 13 falls between segment_start and segment_end from that row (6 and 20, respectively), and the 'chromosome' value from df1 row 7 is 1, just as 'chromosome' in df2 row 2 is 1.

Each row in df1 belongs to one of the segments described in df2; that is, it lies on the same chromosome as one of the segments, and its 'position' is >=segment_start and <=segment_end. And I want to get that information into df1, so it says what segment each position belongs to.

I was thinking of using an if function, and started with:

```
if(df1$position>=df2$segment_start & df1$position<=df2$segment_end & df1$chromosome==df2$chromosome) df1$segment<-df2$segment.number
```

But am not sure that way will be feasible. If nothing else maybe the code can help illustrate what it is I'm trying to do. Basically, I want match each row by its position and chromosome to a segment in df2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a rolling join. You can use `data.table` for this

```
require(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(df1, key = c('chromosome','position'))
DT2 <- data.table(df2, key = c('chromosome','section_start'))
# this will perform the join you want (but retain all the 
# columns with names names of DT2)
# DT2[DT1, roll=TRUE]
# which is why I have renamed and subset here) 
DT2[DT1, roll=TRUE][ ,list(chromosome,position = segment_start,segment.number)]
#     chromosome position segment.number
# 1:           1        1            1.1
# 2:           1        2            1.1
# 3:           1        4            1.1
# 4:           1        5            1.1
# 5:           1        7            1.2
# 6:           1       12            1.2
# 7:           1       13            1.2
# 8:           1       15            1.2
# 9:           1       21            1.3
# 10:          1       23            1.3
# 11:          1       24            1.3
# 12:          2        1            2.1
# 13:          2        5            2.1
# 14:          2        7            2.1
# 15:          2        8            2.2
# 16:          2       12            2.2
# 17:          2       15            2.2
# 18:          2       18            2.3
# 19:          2       21            2.3
# 20:          2       22            2.3
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked too. I was not familiar with the data.table package, but it looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to check out the GenomicRanges package from Bioconductor. It provides the data structures that are appropriate for your use case.

First, we create the `GRanges` objects:

```
gr1 <- with(df1, GRanges(chromosome, IRanges(position, width=1L)))
gr2 <- with(df2, GRanges(chromosome, IRanges(segment_start, segment_end),
                         segment.number=segment.number))
```

Then we find the overlaps and do the merge:

```
hits <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
gr1$segment[queryHits(hits)] <- gr2$segment.number[subjectHits(hits)]
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to GRanges. Do you know how one would export the tables from gr1 or gr2? It is an "S4 class" so write.table doesn't work.

Comment: How would you like to export them? Call `rtracklayer::export(gr1, "my.bed")` to export as BED; GFF is another option. You can always coerce to data frame with `as.data.frame` and proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the regions in `df2` are non-overlapping, continuous and complete (not missing any positions from `df1`). I seem to do this differently every time I try, so here's my latest idea.

First, make sure chromosome is a factor in both data sets

```
df1$chromosome<-factor(df1$chromosome)
df2$chromosome<-factor(df2$chromosome)
```

Now I want to unwrap, chr/pos into one over all generic position, i'll do that with

```
ends<-with(df2, tapply(segment_end, chromosome, max))
offset<-head(c(0,cumsum(ends)),-1)
names(offset)<-names(ends)
```

This assigns unique position values to all positions across all chromosomes and it tracks the offset to the beginning of each chromosome in this new system. Now we will build a translation function from the data in `df2`

```
seglookup <- approxfun(with(df2, offset[chromosome]+segment_start), 1:nrow(df2),
    method="constant", rule=2)
```

We use `approxfun` to find the right interval in the genetic position space for each segment. Now we use this function on `df1`

```
segid <- with(df1, seglookup(offset[chromosome]+position))
```

Now we have the correct ID for each position. We can verify this by merging the data and looking at the results

```
cbind(df1, df2[segid,-1])

   chromosome position segment_start segment_end segment.number
1           1        1             1           5            1.1
2           1        2             1           5            1.1
3           1        4             1           5            1.1
4           1        5             1           5            1.1
5           1        7             6          20            1.2
6           1       12             6          20            1.2
7           1       13             6          20            1.2
8           1       15             6          20            1.2
9           1       21            21          25            1.3
10          1       23            21          25            1.3
11          1       24            21          25            1.3
12          2        1             1           7            2.1
13          2        5             1           7            2.1
14          2        7             1           7            2.1
15          2        8             8          16            2.2
16          2       12             8          16            2.2
17          2       15             8          16            2.2
18          2       18            18          22            2.3
19          2       21            18          22            2.3
20          2       22            18          22            2.3
```

So it looks like we did alright.